# Dynamic dataframe transformation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a specific problem which I cannot solve it seems.
The dataframe is basically a converted list of lists (from a JavaScript object output) to a dataframe which needs to stay in this format (dataframe).
It basically looks like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. registry |  |  |  |
| key1 |  |  |  |
| attribute1 | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| attribute2 | value2 |  |  |
| 2. registry |  |  |  |
| key2 |  |  |  |
| attribute1 | value1 |  |  |
| 3. registry |  |  |  |
| key1 |  |  |  |
| attribute3 | value4 | value5 | value6 |

The desired output would be something like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Registry | Key | attribute1 | attribute2 | attribute3 |
| 1. registry | key1 | value1 | value2 | NA |
| 1. registry | key1 | value2 | NA | NA |
| 1. registry | key1 | value3 | NA | NA |
| 2. registry | key2 | value1 | NA | NA |
| 3. registry | key1 | NA | NA | value4 |
| 3. registry | key1 | NA | NA | value5 |
| 3. registry | key1 | NA | NA | value6 |

The problem is that it cannot be hard-coded, because I don't know the number of attributes, the number of values and the exact number of registries beforehand. So it could be any numbers basically.
Only one key belongs to one registry, but it varies, so it's basically a categorical variable in my interpretation.

My first intention was to add a new column partitioned by the registries (labeled on them with regex), then transform it to wide format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your example is not clear enough. Its hard to tell how you manually got to the desired output

Comment: Can you share the JavaScript object output without converting it to dataframe?